# Is it recommended to explicitly call browser.driver.quit() when running a test suite with protractor? Or does the protractor API do that for you?

Tags: protractor

I am running my protractor test suite in firefox driver as part of the continuous integration process. We connect to selenium server on the grid. I have a onPrepare block as part of my test suite that logs a user in and an onComplete that logs the user out. I do not explicitly call driver.quit. Is it required? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessary since [runner teardownEnv](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/35dcea01bf/lib/runner.js#L418) will take care of that for you.